# Less: Can't use Map inside each

Tags: css, less

I have following less:

```
@threshold:{
  a:50;
  b:200;
};

@themes:{
  a:red;
  b:blue;
};

.mymixin(@name,@color,@thrshld){
  //do-something
}

each(@themes,{
  .mymixin(@key,@value,@threshold[@key]);
});
```

By running the code, following error occurs:

> RuntimeError: error evaluating function `each`: variable @key not found...

I'm using v3.9.0

How can I use Maps in each function?

Comment: See http://lesscss.org/features/#maps-feature actually. If I'm not mistaken `@threshold[@key]` will look for a variable named `@key` *inside* `@threshold` (and there's no). To get to a property value of the `@threshold` named as specified by the value of the 'each's'` `@key` variable - use `@threshold[$@key]`.
(I.e. it's important to realize the difference between all these `a[b]`, `a[@b]`, `a[$b]`, `a[@@b]` and `a[$@b]` statements).

Comment: Yeah it's true, thanks, but I prefer to use `@threshold(@key)`

Comment: `@threshold(@key)` makes sense (though personally I find this particular syntax yet more confusing for readability - too many syntactic sugar variations to remember for the tiny single feature :(.

Comment: OMG ! it's not working at all ! but with your solution is working, I'm deleting the answer, so you can answer and I'll accept.

Comment: Don't bother (I'm too lazy to write answers anyway). It would be helpful for future readers if you add both options into the A (I guess this would be quite common Q since the neither `*a[$@b]` nor `@a($@b)`syntax is explicitly documented yet. E.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/54400988/2712740).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the `@map[$@property]` syntax to evaluate the value of `@map[@property]`

```
.mymixin(@name, @color, @thrshld) {
  .theme-@{name} {
    color: @color;
    width: @thrshld;
  }
}

@threshold: {
  a: 50;
  b: 200;
};

@themes: {
  a: red;
  b: blue;
};

each(@themes, {
  .mymixin(@key, @value, @threshold[$@key])
})
```